# Validating date input field in parsley js

Tags: laravel, date, parsley

For some reason, I don't have datepicker for the date input field and I want to allow to enter value in `mm/dd/yyyy` format only. I've used parsley js for validation.

Somehow, I've managed to validate email, image, digits field and i don't find built in validation method for date.

Is there any parsley rule for the date ?

Comment: I've searched and i don't get something like that, do you have any idea ?

Comment: Please share your thoughts

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. It's unfortunately not documented but it was added in version 2.7 according to the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

The date parse code is [here](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/blob/master/src/parsley/utils.js#L109)

It expects YYYY-MM-DD so you could do something like

```
<input type="text" id="somedate"
       placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"
       data-parsley-type="date"
       data-parsley-type-message="Date must be YYYY-MM-DD"
       data-parsley-mindate="{{ today|date:'Y-m-d' }}"
       data-parsley-mindate-message="Date must be after today"
       required>
```